# How to convert a Simple Java String to EBCDIC with packed decimal format

Tags: java, string, ebcdic, packed-decimal

i have to convert all the data in file to EBCDIC with packed decimal format.

all the data in the file is in simple text format.

As per my knowledge we will need to convert the ASCII to EBCDIC Cp1047 or some other format first and then apply “packed decimal” logic/code.(may be i am wrong)

the converted format should be like "C3 C5 40 F0 C9 F8"(i.e. EBCDIC packed decimal format)

Comment: If it is not directly sported... start be reading format documentation... Not really sure what you are looking for from SO. Maybe just use search - since you probably can't use search engine like https://www.bing.com/search?q=Java+String+to+EBCDIC here is possible result  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368603/convert-string-from-ascii-to-ebcdic-in-java

Comment: Do you have a format description for your file? Do you know *exactly* where the COMP-3 fields are? It would be great if you'd provide an example line and description

Comment: Your example is NOT packed decimal; it is ALMOST *zoned* decimal, where the last digit (usually) or first digit (sometimes) -- but not one in the middle -- is Cx or Dx. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10545291/2868801

Answer (score 0):

Packed Decimal (Comp3 in Cobol)

- +123 is stored as x'123C'
- -123 is stored as x'123D'
- unsigned 123 is x'123F'

---

Do you have a **Cobol Copybook** ???, if you do, see [JRecord Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093560/how-to-read-a-date-in-java-from-a-comp-3-field-in-cobol/34097809#34097809).
JRecord also has

- [Csv to Cobol](https://sourceforge.net/p/jrecord/wiki/Cobol2Csv,%20Csvl2Cobol/) program (Convert a Csv file to Cobol using a Cobol Copybook)
- [Xml-to-Cobol](https://sourceforge.net/p/jrecord/wiki/Data2Xml%20and%20Xml2Data/) program (Convert a Xml file to Cobol using a Cobol Copybook)

Alternatives to **JRecord** are

- Cobol2J
- legstar
- various commercial products

**Note:** I am the author of JRecord

---

Converting a number to Packed Decimal is pretty easy and there are a number of ways to do it

#### Convert to String

one option is

1. Convert the number to a String
2. Add the sign Character to the end of the String
3. Convert the String to Bytes (Hex-String)

Java Code to convert an integer to Packed-Decimal

```
    String val = Integer.toString(Math.abs(value));
    if (value < 0) {
        val = val.substring(1) + "D"
    } else {
        val += "C";
    }

    byte[] bytes = (new BigInteger(val, BASE_16)).toByteArray();
```

---

#### Similar Question

[How to convert unpacked decimal back to COMP-3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337912/how-to-convert-unpacked-decimal-back-to-comp-3/4343256#4343256)

Comment: thank you for the answer but my file contain characters also along with the integers something like "Hi N456 The End" and this string i want to convert in format like "C1 60 C1 4B F2 F5 F9 4B F5 F0 F0".

Comment: What has packed decimal got to do with anything ???; Have a look at the OutputStreamWriter class, in particular characterset parameter